# Custom "username" for github pages, but not a custom domain

Tags: github-pages

I decided to build a small blog using [github pages](https://pages.github.com). I already have a github account, with some username, but I don't want my blog to be `myusername.github.io`, I would rather prefer `myblogname.github.io`...

The reason is that I want some minimal customization, but without paying for a custom domain.

Is is possible (without changing my username)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With your current username create an [organization](https://github.com/organizations/new) with the name of the blog. Then under the organization create the repo organizationname.github.io.